# How send complex Object thru Loopback REST via Android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, loopbackjs

I use loopback on server with an android client.

I want to use the RESTfull API to send from Android (with the Loopback SDK) a object like this in Android :

```
public class MyRESTObject extends Model {

private String name;
private String date;
private HashMap<String, MySubObject> content;


private static void run(Activity activity) {
    final MySubObject myContent = new MySubObject();
    myContent.setValues(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
                            put("A", 1);
                            put("B", 2);
                        }}
    );

    myContent.setTexts(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                           put("Q", "Bonjour");
                           put("S", "Aurevoir");
                       }}
    );

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), "https://x.herokuapp.com:443/api");
    ObjectRepository repository = adapter.createRepository(ObjectRepository.class);

    MyRESTObject myObject = repository.createObject(ImmutableMap.of("date", new Date()));
    myObject.name = "hello";
    myObject.content = new HashMap<String, MySubObject>() {{
        put("1", myContent);
        put("2", myContent);
    }};
    myObject.save(new VoidCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

public class ObjectRepository extends ModelRepository<MyRESTObject> {

    public ObjectRepository() {
        super("Tasting", MyRESTObject.class);
    }
}
}

public class MySubObject {
    public HashMap<String, Integer> values;

    public HashMap<String, String> getTexts() {
        return texts;
    }

    public void setTexts(HashMap<String, String> texts) {
        this.texts = texts;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(HashMap<String, Integer> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> texts;
}
```

Now in Loopback, I defined a model like this :

```
"properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
```

When I get the post request at server level, I got the following JSON

```
{
  "name":"myName",
  "date":"2015-06-01",
  "content":{
    "name1":"javaObjectRef1",
    "name2":"javaObjectRef2",
    "name3":"javaObjectRef3"
  }
}
```

and I expect more :

```
{
  "name":"myName",
  "date":"2015-06-01",
  "content":{
    "name1":{
      "values" : {
         "A":"1",
         "B":"10
       },
      "texts": {
         "Q":"Bonjour",
         "S":"Aurevoir"
       }
     },
    ...
}
```

How can I do to get the full deep content ?

Comment: Please provide the sourcecode you used to parse your `MyRESTObject` to a JSON Object

Comment: ok I added the android part to save the file. On server file I do nothing and expect loopback to save the object as a document doesn"t matter how it is built !